# jQuery: Implementing UI Autocomplete on hidden Div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement JQuery UI's Autocomplete feature into a div that is initially hidden. I would assume I need to use the .live function, but I'm not sure how to implement that into the source they give. Any help?

```
$(function() {
        var availableTags = [
            "ActionScript",
            "AppleScript",
            "Asp",
            "BASIC",
            "C",
            "C++",
            "Clojure",
            "COBOL",
            "ColdFusion",
            "Erlang",
            "Fortran",
            "Groovy",
            "Haskell",
            "Java",
            "JavaScript",
            "Lisp",
            "Perl",
            "PHP",
            "Python",
            "Ruby",
            "Scala",
            "Scheme"
        ];
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

Comment: @mu: figured it out. Essentially, I needed to call the function to add the available tags within the hidden div (I'm using PHP). That way, the tags show up. The autocomplete wasn't populating if I called the list from the header for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The live function only works for attaching events, such as "click" or "hover" etc.

You can still use autocomplete on an input element that is hidden, and you can hide and show the element (or its containing DIV) as much as you like.